# Schema not found exception in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-schema-registry

I got a schema not found exception after I am setting the cleanup policy to schema registry.

The error is (`stack_trace`):

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error retrieving Avro schema for id 425
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Schema not found; error code: 40403
at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:209)
```

everything is working before updating and restart the schema registry.

Comment: Well, prove to us that id 425 actually exists

Comment: The cleanup policy of the Registry topic must be compact, by the way, and this is the default, so what exactly did you change?

Comment: my schema registry was stopped and it says the below issues. The retention policy of the schema topic _schemas is incorrect. You must configure the topic to 'compact' cleanup policy to avoid Kafka deleting your schemas after a week. So, that I changed the policy to compact. after changing it, I got schema not found error in my all java application.

Comment: Makes sense. It was previously not compacting (so was deleting, as the message says). And now that schema cannot be found. Again, you've not proven that it should exist, which you don't need to do using a Java application. E.g. `curl http://registry:8081/schemas/ids/425`. And if it doesn't exist, there is nothing you can do here; the ID was already written into your topic, and cannot be changed, so you must skip over those records

Comment: if schema is changed we have to register is once with producerProps.put("auto.register.schemas", true);, for subsequent request we can set it to false.

Answer (score 0):

> everything is working before updating and restart the schema registry

The Registry maintains an internal HashMap. If you restart it, the map must be rebuilt.

If the `_schemas` topic that is used to rebuild the topic is misconfigured to not compact data, then schemas will be deleted.

Meanwhile, any schema IDs that were previously produced into the other topics your apps are using are now invalid.